# Cannot install beautifulsoup4==4.9.1 and textract==1.6.3 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, requirements.txt

I am trying to run a Github project https://github.com/Aveek-Saha/Movie-Script-Database

The **requirements.txt** has *beautifulsoup4*==4.9.1 and *textract*==1.6.3 in it but when I run it in my Terminal in VS I get the following error msg.

```
ERROR: Cannot install beautifulsoup4==4.9.1 and textract==1.6.3 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
 The user requested beautifulsoup4==4.9.1
 textract 1.6.3 depends on beautifulsoup4==4.8.0

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit <https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies>
```

I don't know enough about the scripts or Pyhton really so I am not confident in changing the Versions.
I am working with the Python Version 3.8.9 right now. I read somewehre that there where problems with the  3.6 Version and beautifulsoup4 but that was fixed as far as I know.

I would be greatful if someone would tell me how to fix this.

Comment: I would try changing the requirements.txt file you downloaded to have beautifulsoup4==4.8.0 , it seems Movie-Script-Database is the package with the version conflict error in this case.

Comment: Version 4.8.0 and 4.9.1 of bs4 should mostly be compatible, read their changelog to confirm there are no breaking changes. You can edit the `requirements.txt` as @WilliamD.Irons suggested to use bs4 version 4.9.1